# Large Data Transfer between enterprise applications

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, apache-kafka, storage

What is the best way to post large data for processing within enterprise applications?

Data

1. will be of size upto 1 GB Data
2. when consumed, can be removed (if processed); need not be persisted.

Can we look at JMS technologies / Kafka Cluster to receive and distribute the data? Data has to be consumed fully, only-ones, and cant be shared(partitioned) across multiple consumers.

What are the other options can be explored?

Answer (score 3):

Apache KAFKA is more designed to handle realtime streams of data rather than large data transfer. Also messages do not delete, rather they are commited. Also exactly once processing would need to be implemented by you. KAFKA by itself is not JTA aware. I would recommend against using large message sizes.

No matter what other queuing technology you use you will need to use message sizes smaller than 1GB (i.e. you will need to chunk your data and reassemble or make your processing stream like instead of bulk).